# Generate page access token facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to create a Messenger bot.
I need to generate a page access token to use it through my app.
However, when I try to generate it, I had the following error

**Warning
Platform Access Disabled: Access temporarily disabled due to changes to the Facebook Platform**

I have looked for it on Google and it seems that Facebook has blocked temporarily access to their platform as they are making modifications...

Is there another way to generate a token?
I'm able to generate a token for the Graph API explorer. Can I use that one through my app?

Thanks.

Comment: in the graph api explorer, make sure to select YOUR app, not the default api explorer app. if that works, you can use the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On March 26 2018, Facebook temporarily paused app review, meaning you cannot create new app/page tokens with specific permissions. According to Facebook:

> We made the following changes:
>
> - Pause app review: We paused app review last week while we implement new changes to our platform.
> - Access to user friends requires Login Review: We are treating user_friends as an extended permission that requires Login Review.

[source](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/03/26/facebook-platform-changes/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your app token in graph api explorer. Please 
[Select your Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83zr3.png) and select which token that you need [select token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjxCw.png).

Comment: I have tried that and it gave me an error with a link: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/ I think I have to wait